# Solr in tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, centos6

I dont seem to be able to find this information anywhere on the internet. So maybe someone can help.

here's my config:

```
<solr persistent="false">

  <!--
  adminPath: RequestHandler path to manage cores.  
    If 'null' (or absent), cores will not be manageable via request handler
  -->
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
     <core name="collection1" instanceDir="." />
  </cores>
```

solr is installed to /opt/solr/ which is also where the solr.xml file is located. it deploys on tomcat7, and I can access the main page, directly at localhost:8080/solr however, I dont see how to add cores, and when I browse to localhost:8080/solr/admin it shows the following error which is the one I really cannot get past:

```
HTTP Status 404 - missing core name in path
type Status report
message missing core name in path
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

its not verbose enough for me to really know exactly whats wrong, being a first time user this is pretty confusing. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of solr.xml from my sandbox. Hope that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
  <cores hostPort="8080"
         hostContext="solr"
         adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="yourcorenamehere"
          instanceDir="coredirectoryhere"
          dataDir="data"
          schema="schema.xml"
          config="solrconfig.xml"
          loadOnStartup="true"
          transient="false" />
  </cores>
</solr>
```